# Retain checked value in multiselect dropdown list angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How to retain checked value in multi select dropdown list angularjs. For an example, I have two multi-select dropdowns, say dropdown1 and dropdown2. If I select checked value from dropdown1 depending upon that id dropdown2 value can filled.

I have selected some values from dropdown2. Then If I OnChange an dropdown1, dropdown2 will get refreshed. How to retain selected values in dropdown2?

Comment: Post your code if you want us to help.

Comment: @Pex Is there anything else I can do, or any other information you can provide that can help us answer this question for you?

Answer (score 0):

Store the value of dropdown2 when it gets selected, then update the logic to your OnChange for dropdown1 that checks if the variable for the value of dropdown2 is null or has some default value that you can initialize it to.

If it's in the "unset" state, then allow dropdown2 to be updated, otherwise leave the value that was selected.